# Asp.net mvc jquery Ajax call params are not past

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am writing an Asp.net MVC application and I have an ajax call:

```
    var email = $("#emailInput").val();
    alert(email);
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Validate",
            data:email,
            dataType:'text',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Validate(string email)
{

}
```

The parameter email is always null. Any ideas?
I've tried sending the email string as a json object, but I've got the same result.

Answer (score 2):

See below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/Validate",
    data: { email: email },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the key and value pair for this to work.

Something like this. var dataPair = {"email": email parameter value here};

url: "/Home/Validate",
            data:dataPair,